# NSTimer not firing when UITextView is scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITextView that I am using to print out a ton of data that I have read from a file. I have it on an `NSTimer` so that 100 times per second I bring in a line of data, print it to the textView and then play around with the data and output some stuff using `NSLog`. However, whenever I scroll the textView I notice that nothing is outputted to the console via `NSLog` until the scrolling is finished.

Does the scroller block the main thread or something?

```
-(void) initialize{
    ...
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(hit:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)hit:(NSTimer*)time{
    double percentage = (double)lineIndex/(double)lines.count;
    //NSLog(@"%f", percentage);
    if (lineIndex < lines.count){
        [self recievedString:[lines objectAtIndex:lineIndex]];
        lineIndex += 1;
    }else{
        [time invalidate];
        timer = nil;
        [self.delegate finished];
    }
}

-(void)recievedString:(NSString *)line{
    NSArray *pieces = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    double accZ = [pieces[0] doubleValue];
    double accMag = [pieces[1] doubleValue];
    double gyroX = [pieces[2] doubleValue];
    double gyroZ = [pieces[3] doubleValue];
    [self crunchDatawithAccZ:accZ andAccMag:accMag andGyroX:gyroX andGyroZ:gyroZ];
}

-(void)crunchDatawithAccZ:(double)accZ andAccMag:(double)accMag andGyroX:(double)gyroX andGyroZ:(double)gyroZ {
    accMag = accMag*ACC_SENSITIVITY/(pow(2,DATA_WIDTH-1));
    accZ = accZ*ACC_SENSITIVITY/(pow(2,DATA_WIDTH-1));
    gyroX = gyroX*GYRO_SENSITIVITY/(pow(2,DATA_WIDTH-1));
    gyroZ = gyroZ*GYRO_SENSITIVITY/(pow(2,DATA_WIDTH-1));

    NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f\n", accZ, accMag, gyroX, gyroZ);
    [self.delegate didReceiveData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f, %f, %f\n", accZ, accMag, gyroX, gyroZ]];

    [gyroX_array addObject:@(fabs(gyroX))];
...
}
```

The delegate method:

```
-(void)didReceiveData:(NSString *)line{
    self.console.text = [self.console.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%@", line];
    [self.console setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.console.contentSize.height) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: A.) Show code B.) what you're doing sounds really wonky

Comment: Whats this got to do with notifications?

Comment: You're right, it's not a notification. It's a timer.

Comment: Scrolling does a lot on the main, but it should leave room for other computation.  The posted code is doing a lot of computing at 100Hz, but I suspect the bigger problem is setting the content offset concurrently during scrolling.  (Consider a quick test at a much larger interval, like 0.5, and commenting out the `setContentOffset` line)

Answer (score 2):

If you check the doc of method

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti target:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)yesOrNo;
```

it says (I highlighted the runloop mode):

> Creates and returns a new NSTimer object and schedules it on the current run loop in the **default mode**.
>   After seconds seconds have elapsed, the timer fires, sending the message aSelector to target.

When iOS tracking touching events, the main runloop runs in UITrackingRunLoopMode. The timer according to your code is register in NSDefaultRunLoopMode(A.K.A the main runloop is not quit busy, maybe just idle or waiting for an event.). So in UITrackingRunLoopMode, the runloop is quite busy to make UIKit responses as smooth as possible.

To solve the problem you need to register your timer in NSRunLoopCommonModes(this value as the mode are monitored by all run loop modes).

Here is the doc excerpt I think helpful to you:

> timers are associated with specific modes of your run loop. If a timer is not in the mode currently being monitored by the run loop, it does not fire until you run the run loop in one of the timer’s supported modes.

Check this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1) if you are not familiar with runloop.

Answer (score 2):

A `UIScrollView` (or any derivative like the `UITextView`) will block the main thread while scrolling to keep the rendering smooth.  This makes your custom timer halt.

To bypass this, a simple way is to add it to the main run loop in mode `NSRunLoopCommonModes`:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(hit:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```